# Grid table jumps out of the main body

Tags: html, css

I am new CSS, HTML if this is dumb question sorry.
I am trying to make a list of items using grid by providing image and text next to it. After finally doing so my grid jumped out of my main part.

Here is the example of what my code looks like:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  max-width: 80vw;
  max-height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
  grid-row-gap: 3%;
}

.box-gap {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  border: black solid;
}

.box-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%
}

.box-text {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <div class="box-gap"></div>
  <image src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/26/14/36/light-bulb-503881_1280.jpg" class="box-image"></image>
  <div class="box-text">
    Text 1
  </div>

  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <div class="box-gap"></div>
  <image src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/26/14/36/light-bulb-503881_1280.jpg" class="box-image"></image>
  <div class="box-text">
    Text 2
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jL4tw7m/9/

I want my container to cover whole grid, right know red container do not fit grid table. I managed to solve this by adding `overflow: auto`, but it looks ugly with two scrollbars.

Comment: Hello, for future readers, please don't give extern code. Instead embed it in your question. (The link can be still there, of course).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review the (guidelines for asking a questions)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].  You are more likely to get answers if you familiarise yourself with the standards of the site.